# JFugue ParserListenerAdapter onChordParsed method not invoked

Tags: java, jfugue

I am trying to read a midi file that contains only a guitar track. The track is made of both single notes and chords.
While i can successfully read all notes through onNoteParsed method, i cannot read chords.
In fact the onChordParsed method is never invoked.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.jfugue.parser.ParserListenerAdapter;
import org.jfugue.theory.Chord;
import org.jfugue.theory.Note;

public class MusicStringParserListener extends ParserListenerAdapter {

    private List<String> tokenList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onNoteParsed(Note note) {
        tokenList.add(note.getToneString() + note.getOctave() + note.getDuration());
    }

    @Override
    public void onChordParsed(Chord chord) {
        System.out.println("onChordParsed entered");
    }
    
    public List<String> getTokenList() {
        return tokenList;
    }
}
```

I tried to change the midi file to insert different kinds of chords, like major, minor or power chords, but still that method is not fired.

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, `onChordParsed` isn't called - and should probably be removed from the API - and `onNoteParsed` is used instead.

**Parsing chords from a Staccato string**

When JFugue processes a chord, it breaks the chord into individual notes - which is necessary to support cases where some of the notes might change in melody during what would otherwise be a chord. As far as JFugue is concerned, "Cmaj" looks just like "C+E+G", but the latter provides more resolution, allowing things like "Cw+Eh_Ebh+Gw".

You can still do what you want, though. When you get an `onNoteParsed` event, the Note will tell you whether it's the first note in a sequence, a next note in a sequence, or another note in melody during a sequence.

For each note coming in, use the note's `isFirstNote()`, `isHarmonicNote()`, and `isMelodicNote()` methods to determine whether a note is in a chord. I believe what you'd see for Cw+Eh_Ebh+Gw is:

- C - first note
- E - harmonic note
- Eb - melodic note
- G - harmonic note

I *think* that a single note that is not part of a chord will have `isFirstNote()` = false, but I'd need to double-check that.

**Parsing chords from MIDI**

Although MIDI data contains timestamps for each Note On and Note Off event, processing chords from MIDI data gets complicated quickly and is beyond what I have been able to implement in JFugue

Here are some of the reasons why chord processing from MIDI is difficult.

1. If the MIDI is a recording of live play, the times may be slightly
   off.
2. There may be notes that are all played together that are not
   part of a single chord, or that are part of two chords, or some
   notes are chord and some are melody.
3. There could be a chord that is played arpeggiated.
4. There are chord inversions to think about.
5. In MIDI, a Note On or Note Off event can appear anywhere in the MIDI stream! Usually, they're in the right temporal order, but this is not necessarily the case. So we couldn't determine a chord until the full MIDI is parsed.
6. Notes that take place at the same time but in different channels should not be chords - but that's an assumption that may not always be true.

I realize there are music notation tools that can read MIDI and resolve chords, but I imagine those come with some assumptions about the music and have undergone a lot of trial and error in their development. As JFugue currently stands, it just reads all MIDI notes as notes. Every note read from MIDI will appear as isFirstNote() with no recognition about whether the note is in harmony or melody.

Comment: :'( unfortunately isFirstNote() returns true even though the note is not part of a chord. I have tested this with a midi i made up with a bar full of single notes. Can you think of another method to achieve this? I would like to use JFugue in my project since it's very simple and straightforward, but i really can't use it if i can't detect when multiple notes are played at the same time

Comment: OK, that needs to be fixed in a future version - and/or, Note could have a method like isPartOfChord. (It should probably also have isRootOfChord.) In the meantime, you'll know if a note is not part of a chord if the *next* note also has isFirstNote = true. That's definitely a workaround, but it ought to work.

Comment: i tried this approach but i cannot make it work. I am open to consider that the midi i have created is encoded in a strange, unparseable way, because i am not an expert of midi by any means. But all the tests i have made so far, with both power chords and proper major/minor chords showed me that isFirstNote() *always* return true, isHarmonicNote() *always* return false and is isMelodicNote() *always* return false.

Comment: Ah, you're parsing MIDI. Sorry, I didn't fully understand your use case. MIDI is a collection of Note On and Note Off events (and other events). When reading MIDI, JFugue has no way to reconstruct what notes are part of chords, and all notes will appear as individual notes. If you were parsing a music string, like "Cmaj" or "C+E+G", you'd see the isHarmonic/isMelodic set correctly, but when reading MIDI, chord information is not present, just the notes themselves.

Comment: Don't we have an indication of the time when an instrument plays a note in JFugue ? Clearly all notes that play at the same time are part of a chord

Comment: It gets complicated quickly. First, if the MIDI is a recording of live play, the times may be slightly off. There may be notes that are all played together that are not part of a single chord, or that are part of two chords, or some notes are chord and some are melody. There could be a chord that is played arpeggiated. There are chord inversions to think about. Which is all to say, it's more work than I wanted to put into it - but I'm always happy to include contributions from the open source community!

Comment: I see... i would be glad to contribute if i had any notion of midi that went beyond the user's basic notion. What should i do about this question? Should i accept the answer you gave or you prefer to write a new one that takes into account what you wrote in the penultimate comment?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include what I had said in my comment.